Office.context empty when calling authentification in Safari 17.4
Since I updated Safari to 17.4
Office context item is empty on the authentification page.
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";

export default (() => {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded, should get client_id and login url from url parameters
  Office.onReady(async (infos) => {
    try {
      const login_url = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("MSAL_LOGIN_URL")?.trim();
      // check if there is localhost on utl  so assign bla to a const otherwise asign blabla
      const client_id = window.location.href.includes("localhost")
        ? "xxxx-2e02d357f9e0"
        : "xxxx-c0c2bd127807";

      const baseUrl = window.location.origin;
      const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: client_id,
          authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
          redirectUri: `${baseUrl}/loginfile.html`,
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: "localStorage", // needed to avoid "login required" error
          storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // recommended to avoid certain IE/Edge issues
        },
      });
      // handleRedirectPromise should be invoked on every page load
      console.log("msalInstance", msalInstance);
      try {
        await msalInstance.initialize();
      } catch (error) {
        Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "error", result: JSON.stringify(error) }));
      }
      msalInstance
        .handleRedirectPromise()
        .then(async (response) => {
          // If response is non-null, it means page is returning from AAD with a successful response
          if (response) {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "success", result: response.accessToken }));
          } else {
            // Otherwise, invoke login
            await msalInstance.loginRedirect({
              scopes: ["profile", "openid", "user.read", "mail.readwrite", "tasks.readwrite"],
            });
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "success", result: response.accessToken }));
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const errorData: string = `errorMessage: ${error.errorCode}
                                 message: ${error.errorMessage}
                                 errorCode: ${error.stack}`;
        });
    } catch (error) {
      Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({ status: "error", result: JSON.stringify(error) }));
    }
  });
})();


When I click on context

In Chrome and Edge it's working.
